# Anaconda install on offline system: "UID: Undefined variable"

Tags: python, linux, anaconda

I have a .sh file to install anaconda on an offline linux system.  Following these instructions:

https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/

When I kick off the script it eventually comes back with:

```
UID: Undefined variable
ERROR: Executing pre_install.sh failed
```

What does this mean and how can I get past it?

Comment: What is the exact command you are using to run the script? The directions indicate to specifically run the script with `bash` which combined with the error you're getting, indicates it's relying on `$UID` (a "bashism") and isn't getting a value for it.

Comment: I'm running: bash ~/Downloads/Anaconda3-5.3.0-Linux-x86_64.sh from csh.  I have also changed to bash and tried executing it or sourcing it, all with the same result.

Comment: Hmm that's odd. Could you maybe try `bash -i` instead? I'm not sure why `bash` isn't setting the UID when you are specifically starting it with that process. One additional check you might want to make is that `bash` is the actual binary that's getting launched, rather than perhaps some compatibility alias like `alias bash=dash` or something. `which bash` should be a real binary, not a symlink or anything like that.